# Is there a "native" Javascript function that modifies an object property

Tags: javascript

Is there a native JavaScript function (or library/module for JavaScript) that modifies a key's value and then returns the full object?

Here's what I've done:

```
function modifyJSON(jsob, key, val) {
    var newjsob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsob));
    newjsob[key] = val;
    return newjsob;
}
```

(Of course, if I wanted to modify the original, I could delete `var newjsob...` and work with jsob directly.)

This works, but if this type of functionality has already been implemented somewhere, I'd prefer to use that than roll my own.

Comment: This is about Javascript objects, nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a way of representing objects and arrays as strings.

Comment: Replacing the value is easy (as you can see, `x[key] = y`). The tricky part is cloning the object, which most places use [the structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) for. If you can run that yourself, you'll have a nice copy that is more robust than to-and-from JSON.

Comment: No native function that does that. Library: maybe, but that's off-topic.

Comment: Why on earth are your stringifying and then immediately parsing?

Comment: @drewmoore `Object.assign` doesn't make a deep copy.

Comment: @torazaburo it's an easy way to make a deep copy of an object with only primitive (or list/object) values.

Comment: So the OP's question is actually to make deep clone, then modify one property, then return the object? That's not what the question says--it says "replace".

Comment: The copy doesn't seem particularly relevant to the question you're asking. You can make a clone if you wish, but if you want to know if there's a method that mutates an object property and returns the object, yes, `Object.defineProperty` does that.

Comment: ...so you could do `return Object.defineProperty(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsob)), key, {value: val})`. Be aware of the impact this has on property descriptors. Read the docs to find out more.

Comment: *Of course, if I wanted to modify the original* And you do, or you do not? You want to copy, or not?

Comment: @torazaburo In my case, not. Essentially, what I want is something like a string replace, but for a JSON type object.  Where `var v="misplled"; v.replace("pl", "pel")` will return `'mispelled'` but not modify `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is a little misleading. What you're doing is deep cloning an existing object and then changing a property on the new object.

If shallow cloning is enough, you could use Object.assign:

```
var update = {};
update[key] = val;
return Object.assign(jsob, update);
```

If you need deep cloning, I would check out [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). When updating any field on an immutable data structure, a clone of the original structure with your updates applied to it is returned. It's pretty much the exact behavior you're written.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the difficult part is the deep cloning. Lodash can deep clone the object for you.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#cloneDeep

```
function modifyJSON(jsob, key, val) {
    var newjsob = _.cloneDeep(jsob);
    newjsob[key] = val;
    return newjsob
}
```

After you get the new object, you can just modify the object's property as you desire.

However, be aware that deep copying is slow. Only use it if you must.

https://jsfiddle.net/38kscyxa/